# Using third party libraries in Google App Engine with php

Tags: php, google-app-engine

Is there any way to add third-party libraries in google app engine for php? I am trying to use php_xmlrpc.dll. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Generally, no.

The list of enabled extensions is here
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/runtime#PHP_Enabled_extensions

There are one or two optional ones like mailparse that you can turn on with php.ini